# Textfile processing: Undo text wrapping (column and line)

Tags: regex, shell, text

I have some very large text files which are the output from an old mainframe application. I no longer have access to the source application but need to perform some data analysis on the output.

The data is basically tab separated values but due to the source system it wraps the values and breaks the output based on width and number of lines

Contents of text files look something like this (this is mockup data):

```
            Page 1:

            Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8
            ------------------------------------------------------------
            1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111
            2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222
            3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333
            4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444
            5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555
            6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666
            7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777
            -----------------------------------------------------------

            Col9    Col10   Col11                   
            --------------------
            1111    1111    1111                    
            2222    2222    2222                    
            3333    3333    3333                    
            4444    4444    4444                    
            5555    5555    5555                    
            6666    6666    6666                    
            7777    7777    7777                    
            --------------------

            Page 2:


            Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8
            ------------------------------------------------------------
            8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888
            9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999
            -----------------------------------------------------------

            Col9    Col10   Col11                   
            --------------------
            8888    8888    8888
            9999    9999    9999                    
            --------------------
```

Pages will continue on for some time.

I would like to convert the files programtically so that the columns are continuous. ie. The final data set would look like a more typical CSV style delimited file.

```
            Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5    Col6    Col7    Col8    Col9    Col10   Col11 
            ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                        
            1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111    1111
            2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222    2222
            3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333    3333
            4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444    4444
            5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555    5555
            6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666    6666
            7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777    7777
            8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888    8888
            9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999    9999
            -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm unsure exactly where to start here - can I use something like AWK to do this or some sort of Regular Expression. Any help as to starting point would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you can do it with `csplit` command and `paste` command.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a parser (e.g. Bison). Something like:

```
goal:pages

pages: pages page

page: header rowsOfColumns { dumpCurrentPage(); }

header: "page" num { curColumn = 0; }

rowsOfColumns: rowsOfColumns aRow

aRow: colHeaders dashes colData dashes

colHeaders: colHeaders aHeader { createNewHeader($aHeader); }

dashes: '-'+

colData: colData aData { addToData(curCol++, $aData); }
```

This a highly incomplete answer but being that nobody commented for the past half hour I decided to share my thoughts. Unfortunately I haven't done parsing in a while so I cannot give a proper answer.